# SVC-SOCBUF error in task server

Tags: marklogic

I am getting `SVC-SOCBUF` errors in my MarkLogic task server. I am spawning lot of `xdmp:http-post` requests to my MarkLogic server. I am not sure whether that is causing the issues. Help me if you have faced similar issues. Any configuration to be modified?

Comment: What's the rest of the error message? It might contain important details.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually an indication that there was something wrong with the response that came back from the remote server that is being called. It has been seen to occur with empty responses.

HTH!