# what is SVC-SOCBUF: Socket error in Marklogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I'm getting below debug level log in my MarkLogic error log I am not sure whether that is causing the issues. Help me if you have faced similar issues. Any configuration to be modified?

> 2020-07-13 08:32:14.612 Debug: HTTPClientRequest::run 1 because SVC-SOCBUF: Socket error: recv 10.162.209.4:55884-10.160.147.150:8080: EOF

> 2020-07-13 08:32:14.773 Debug: HTTPClientRequest::run 1 because SVC-SOCBUF: Socket error: recv 10.162.209.4:55888-10.160.147.150:8080: EOF

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/messages/SVC-en/SVC-SOCBUF

> **Cause**
> A host operating system socket function returned an unexpected error while MarkLogic was performing buffered I/O on a socket. The host operating system function, socket name, and error message are included in the error report. MarkLogic uses host operating system sockets for communicating over the network.

> **Response**
> See the host operating system documentation for the precise meaning of the error message. Restarting MarkLogic on the host may clear a persistent error condition. Restarting the operating system on the host may clear a persistent error condition.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698563/14419

> It is usually an indication that there was something wrong with the response that came back from the remote server that is being called. It has been seen to occur with empty responses.

Comment: Last weekend I have restarted(ML service & Unix servers) all the hosts in the cluster but still, I'm getting the same error. @Mads Hansen

Comment: Do you know what modules are being executed when these are seen? Is there a pattern to when they appear or is it only on one of your appservers? Is it possible that these are returning empty sequences? Do you have anything hitting your server like load balancer health check pings or scanning/vulnerability tools?